# What happens if vegetation tiles can't be placed?

Tags: ishtar

In *Ishtar: Gardens of Babylon*, the board gets progressively filled up.

On your turn, if you can't place the next tile, would you be forced to pay gems to advance to a tile you could place?

Furthermore, if the game is not over, (fewer than two vegetation piles are empty) but none of the tiles can be placed, what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly there isn’t an answer to this.  On [this bgg rules question](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2303205/impossible-place-vegetation-tile) the designer agreed with a post suggesting the game had been set up wrong and said as follows.

> I have no way to prove that there is no situation where it's not
> possible to place a tile, but until today, each time someone asked
> this question, he forbid to remove tiles related to number of players

There was not suggestion as what to do if it was impossible just appearing to state the game had been set up incorrectly.

In my view if there is no legal move that should be treated as an end game condition but the rules nor the designer have an official answer.